# Trying to store linked list alphabetically

Tags: c

i m trying to sort the linked list alphabetically  in function "trier()" which i'm trying to compare every node name with the next one.

I've tried to compare the nodes name using "strcmp" and then swapping their data.
"patient" is the record.
"exchnage" functions are to swap the data of the node.

```
void trier(){
  struct patient *ptr = tete;
  struct patient*prec=NULL;
  int echange;

  do{
    echange=0;

    while(ptr->suivant!=NULL){
      prec=ptr;
      ptr=ptr->suivant;
      if(strcmp(prec->nom,ptr->nom)<0){
        echangedeNom(prec,ptr);
        echangedePrenom(prec,ptr);
        echangedesentiers(prec,ptr);
        echangedesannes(prec,ptr);
        echange=1;
      }
    }
  }while(echange==1);
  printf("\n\n Trie Avec Succes ! \n");
}
```

it works for the first 2 nodes but later Nope.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

```
void trier(){
  struct patient *ptr = tete;
  struct patient*prec=NULL;
  int echange;

  do{
    echange=0;

    while(ptr->suivant!=NULL){
      prec=ptr;
      ptr=ptr->suivant;
      if(strcmp(prec->nom,ptr->nom)<0){
        echangedeNom(prec,ptr);
        echangedePrenom(prec,ptr);
        echangedesentiers(prec,ptr);
        echangedesannes(prec,ptr);
        echange=1;
      }
    }
  }while(echange==1);
  printf("\n\n Trie Avec Succes ! \n");
}
```

when you finish the internal *while* you missed to set *ptr* back to the head of the list for the next turn, so `ptr->suivant!=NULL` is false and `echange` stay 0 and you stop to sort

can be :

```
void trier(){
  int echange;

  do{
    struct patient *ptr = tete;
    struct patient*prec=NULL;

    echange=0;

    while(ptr->suivant!=NULL){
      prec=ptr;
      ptr=ptr->suivant;
      if(strcmp(prec->nom,ptr->nom)<0){
        echangedeNom(prec,ptr);
        echangedePrenom(prec,ptr);
        echangedesentiers(prec,ptr);
        echangedesannes(prec,ptr);
        echange=1;
      }
    }
  }while(echange==1);
  printf("\n\n Trie Avec Succes ! \n");
}
```

Note an other way was to exchange the cells rather that to exchange their contents